# Where Constant goes in $e^{\int{x dx}}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$e^{\int{x dx}}$$
When integral is an exponent of $e$, where does the constant go? In examples from the books, results of this integral usually omit constant like so:
$$e^{\int{x dx}} = e^{\frac{x^{2}}2}$$
How come? Where did constant go?

Example:
$$ m(x) = e^{\int{\frac{1}x +1 dx}} = e^{ln(x) + x + c} = x*e^x $$
Where $m(x)$ is an integrating factor of some other ODE.

Comment: Is this pertaining to the integrating factor technique of solving differential equations ?

Comment: could you explain the context. Is it a solution of a differential equation.

Comment: What equation ? Please show us.

Comment: I'm solving 1st order linear, non-homogeneous DE using integration factor.

Comment: So this is the my $m(x)$, and if I omit $c$ in this intermediate step, I come to a clean solution. I just wanted to know why I'm omitting the constant at the intermediate steps, rather than just following what prof said

Comment: added the equation to the main question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of differential equations, the constant goes away since usually, any function that differentiates to the integrand will be a solution so people just choose $C = 0$ for convenience. When you keep the constant as a free variable, then you get something like
$$
e^{x^2/2+C_0} = e^{C_0}e^{x^2/2} = C_1e^{x^2/2},
$$
which indicates that any positive constant multiple of the solution will also be a solution.

Comment: Can you please express this phrase "any function that differentiates to the integrand will be a solution" as a formula? It seems too familiar (and I understand math formulas better than math words (:   )

Comment: You mentioned that you are solving a first order nonhomogeneous differential equation so I'll go with that. When you want to solve $y'(t) = \alpha(t)y + \beta(t)$, then any function $A(t)$ such that $A'(t) = \alpha(t)$ will be suitable for a solution of the form $y(t) = e^{A(t)}\int_{t_0}^t e^{-A(s)}\beta(s)~ds$.

Comment: Everythying you said makes sense. And you have answered the question. Thank you.
Though it lead to another question. in a given example when I integrate m(x), in order to check it's validity, I would take the derivative of it and the result would be the same as the initial condition. But it's not in this case. Why? $$ m(x) = e^{\int{\frac{1}x +1 dx}} = e^{ln(x) + x + c} = x*e^x $$
$$dy/dx(x*e^x)=e^x (x+1)$$
$$ e^x (x+1)  !=  e^{\frac{1}x+1} $$

Comment: I assume you're solving the differential equation
$$
y'(t) = \left(\frac1x+1\right)y. 
$$
When you follow the procedure for first order linear equations, you get that the solution is $y(t) = C_0e^{\int\frac1x+1~dx} = C_0e^{\log x + x + C} = \left(C_0e^C\right)\left(xe^x\right) = C_1xe^x$. Then indeed, $$
y'(t) = C_1e^x(x+1) = C_1xe^x\left(1+\frac1x\right) = y\left(1+\frac1x\right).
$$
I hope that clears it up!

Comment: Ah! I see the error of my way.
Thank you for helping me out!